# In a RABL template, how do I round some numbers but not others?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabl

In the JSON output of my app, I need most of the non-integer (i.e. float) numeric values to be shown rounded to a single decimal place i.e. 1.7777 would be shown as 1.8.

I have done this by monkey-patching Float's as_json method:

```
class Float
  def as_json(options={})
    self.round 1
  end
end
```

I'm not even sure if this is a good idea, I've just done it because I can't figure out to specify formats for numeric values in my RABL templates.

But now I also need to show certain values (latitude and longitude) without any rounding whatsoever:

```
object @foo
attributes :bar, :latitude, :longitude
```

How can I tell RABL to round some values (bar) but not others (latitude, longitude)?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question in your original context, in a RABL template, you'd simply create custom nodes for those attributes that you need additional processing on, e.g.

```
object @foo
attributes :bar
node(:latitude) { |foo| f.latitude.round(1) }
node(:longitude) { |foo| f.longitude.round(1) }
```

Comment: Actually it's the other way around. I need latitude and longitude in full; all *other* numbers (and there are many other numbers) should be shown rounded to a single decimal place. If possible I'd rather not have to do this rounding on every instance of the other numbers as it's going to clutter the template too much...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to do is create a view model to handle this logic for you.  Check out the [draper gem](https://github.com/drapergem/draper).

Wrapping your object in a view model allows you to define methods that are specific to the function of "displaying" the object (in this case, its JSON representation).  You would define the bar method on your view model, which rounds the value accordingly.  Since draper uses a Decorator pattern, you get your longitude and latitude methods for free since they're part of your underlying object.  You would then pass your view model to the rabl template.

Comment: Of course! The decorator pattern is perfect for this. Thanks for link to the gem also.

Comment: This works, but the whole point of RABL is that it moves JSON to the view layer *without* the need for a dedicated view model.